# What is the cleanest way to return the error when matching a Result<T, E>?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I'm calling a function that returns a `Result<T, E>` and I want to handle the `Ok` case but return the `Err` as is if an error is returned. What is the cleanest way to do this?

For example, I have:

```
fn example() -> Result<(), Error> {
    match foo() {
        Ok(v) => bar(v),
        Err(e) => Err(e),
    }
}
```

What are some alternate forms of writing this? It feels weird to re-wrap `e` in another `Err` in every call in the stack. Also, every call is basically 4 lines of boilerplate... I'm just looking for a way to simplify and make it more readable. My desire is to have it return the error if error, else process the result value.

Comment: `let v = foo()?` will propagate the error up. See [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/error-handling-and-panics/the-question-mark-operator-for-easier-error-handling.html) example in the rust documentation.

Comment: **Please** take the time to read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/). In this case, [Recoverable Errors with Result](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html).

Comment: This is the relevant part:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rust includes an ['error propagation' operator, `?`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator). If the value of the `Result` it is called on is `Ok` it will unwrap and return the inner value. If the value is `Err` it will return from the function and pass the `Err` to the caller.

```rust
fn example() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let v = foo()?;
    bar(v);
}
```

Comment: Oh my god you're a life saver. I recall seeing this but I think it was before the gravity of the Result type stuck and so didn't retain it.

Comment: interesting but sounds dangerous